# java regex to exclude specific weight from a larger string with date

Tags: java, regex, extract

I have some string

**"Today 31.12.2014g we receive goods. These weight is 31.12g (23.03.2014)"**

31.12.2014**g** - its not mistake. Some text with date label have **g** letter (without space)

I need extract from string only weight value (without date value),
but my regex:

`[0-9]+\.[0-9]+g`

exctact date too :(

my results (two group):

> 12.2014g
>
> 31.12g  <- i am need only this!!!

Comment: Is date format in your data always `dd.mm.yyyy`(sometimes with `g`) and weight `xxxxx.xxg` like `123.00g`? Or is date like `2014.12.31g` also possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to make sure that  before part you are interested in there is nothing you don't want which in your case seems to be

- lets say between 1 and 10 numbers with dot after it like in case

  ```
  31.12.2014g
  ^^^
  ```
- also to make sure that we will match entire value and not just part of it like in case

  ```
  31.12.2014g
      ^^^^^^^
  ```

  where `2.2014g` fulfils condition of previous negative look behind we need to make sure that matched part should not have any digit before it

So try maybe something like

```
(?<!\\d{1,10}\\.)(?<!\\d)\\d+\\.\\d+g
```

BTW `\d` (which in Java is written as `"\\d"`) represents `[0-9]`. You can change it back if you want.

Demo:

```
String data = "Today 31.12.2014g we receive goods. These weight is 31.12g (23.03.2014)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d{1,10}\\.)(?<!\\d)\\d+\\.\\d+g");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output: `31.12g`

Answer (score 2):

You could search for white spaces:

`\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+g   // -> " 31.12g"`

… always assume there are exactly two decimal positions:

`[^\.][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}g   // -> "31.12g"` (though, this will fail if the date is spelled DD.MM.YYg)

… or work *with* the date:

`[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]g?.+(\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+g)   // -> "31.12.2014g we receive goods. These weight is 31.12g", "31.12g"`